# irritation in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, harmonics, distortion

I have written some measurement commands in LTSpice to calculate the weighted harmonic distortion (PWHD)

.meas a1n INTEG (I(Lgra)*cos(2*n*180*fg*time))

.meas an PARAM a1n*2*fg
....

(if somebody wants it I can give you the full text. It works)

The problem is that I want to run it for harmonics n=14 to 40. 
Is there a way to do that without running the simulation again for a different n? (I have already tried the step command and it takes too much time)

Comment: You could generate a script with .meas commands externally and run it on the simulation manually.

Comment: is that possible in LTspice? Or do you mean that I need to export the data and use python, matlab or something similar?

Comment: just use this "run .meas script from file" functionality

Comment: It seems that LTspice cannot calculate the INTEG (I(Lgra)*cos(2*n*180*fg*time)) from a script, although it is possible when the .meas commands are in the model.